# Salesforce formula field - get current date as percentage of overall timeline

Tags: apex, formula-field, date

I have the following fields on my object: `startDate__c` and `endDate__c`.

The length of time between these 2 dates is equal to 100% of the overall timeline.

In a formula field, how can I get today's date as a % of that timeline?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the exact problem you are facing? Did you already try anything?

Comment: @Guy I have a progress bar which represents the timeline. As we move from the start date to the end date, the bar fills. If that makes sense.

Comment: I was just hoping you tried something already instead of asking for a ready-made answer.  My own experience is  that I learn and remember better that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need something like this

```
If TODAY is Between START and END dates, 
then 
(END - TODAY) / (END - START)
```

if that's the case, create a formula % field and try the below formula

```
IF(
  AND(TODAY() >= startDate__c , TODAY() <= endDate__c),
  (endDate__c - TODAY()) / (endDate__c - startDate__c) ,
  NULL
)
```